# Laravel query builder to build mySql query

Tags: laravel-8

I have following two table

user

```
id  name
1   a
2   b
```

DLRS

```
id  user_id  status       cal_duration
'1' '1',     'Answered'     00:01:14
'2' '1',     'Answered'     00:01:14
'3' '1',     'Unanswered'   00:30:14 
'4' '1',     'Unanswered'   00:01:14
'5' '2',     'Answered'     60:00:00
'6' '2',     'Unanswered'   00:25:00
```

I want following result  using laravel.

```
user Dailed_count call_connected call_filed  1-30_second
1      2          2                2         2
```

only user is come from user table and other is count.

I have made two model

user and  Dlrs.

Added relation
In user model
user has many Dlrs

```
public function dlrs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Dlr::class);
}
```

In Dlrs model
Dlrs has one user

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Please suggest.

following give me full record
$data = Dlr::latest()->with('user')->get();

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By The i have completed using following code

```
DB::table('dlrs')
            ->select(
                "users.username", 
                "dlrs.IVR_name",
                DB::raw("COUNT(user_id) AS diled_calls"), 
                DB::raw("sum(case when status='Answered' then 1 else 0 end) as connected_calls"),
                DB::raw("sum(case when status='Unanswered' then 1 else 0 end) as failed_calls"))
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'dlrs.user_id')
            ->groupBy('dlrs.user_id', 'dlrs.IVR_name')
            ->get();
```